# My external hard drive won't open properly on Windows 7 (64-bit)

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive

I have a WD My Passport 1TB USB3.0 drive (`wdbbep0010bsl`) with multiple partitions. Pretty much all of my games/work are on a NTFS partition (~300GB). The rest is dived up into various unused Mac partitions/free space (from when I used a Mac simultaneously).

For quite some time, the drive worked perfectly and I never had any problems with it. However, it started to become really slow (games weren't as playable) so I let AVG do a thorough defrag. After 48 hours it was 7% complete, even though it was only 27% fragmented. I stopped the defrag, ready to continue another time as I needed to use the drive. However, from then on my speeds were ~4KB/s read and 100B/s write (occasionally the drive would jump back up to normal speeds). I was worried I would lose all my data so I unplugged the drive and didn't use it for the last week, waiting for another drive to arrive so that I could transfer the data.

Skip to today, I plug in the internal 320GB drive, and it opens up perfect. I plug in my external drive and instead of being called `STORAGE` it is called `Local Disk`, and there is no size indicator underneath. I open Disk Management, it hangs. I try to open the disk, explorer crashes. I run chkdsk, it hangs (still responding, but the only output after `chkdsk G: /X` was the blinking cursor on the next line. I am running in safe mode as I do not want any background processes interfering with the process.

I don't mind if the drive dies completely, as long as I can get the data onto the new drive. Please can someone help me recover the data, thanks in advance.

Moral of the story: back the hell up.

EDIT: As a rather worrying sign, my external drive does not appear to be making any noise (the access light is lit up, however there does not seem to be a noise from the drive).

EDIT 2: Well, I restarted my PC for something else and when it turned on the drive was spinning up just fine. However as Windows loaded I noticed that all the other symptoms were still showing and after a while, the drive stopped again.

Comment: Sounds like the drive.  It *might* work if you remove it from its enclosure and use a different one.  Honestly the drive sounds like it was already on its last leg.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're suggesting there. Take the drive out of the plastic case?

Comment: If the drive won't spin up your choices are fewer - try a new enclosure in case that's the problem. If not, you're down to folk tales like keep it in the freezer a couple of days; or data recovery specialists [v. expensive]

Comment: Because of the type of drive being specialized my comment about removing it wouldn't even work.

Comment: OK thanks for the help, I'm looking to see if I can find an enclosure somewhere online.

Comment: Where would the best place to find an enclosure be? I know the model of my drive: `wdbbep0010bsl`

Comment: There is no point in getting a different enclosure as this WD My Passport drive will not work that way. This model has the USB attached directly to the PCB and there is no SATA interface inside. Furthermore there is hardware encryption in place, so even if swap the PCB the data won't be readable. At this point your best option is professional data recovery. You can have a look at WD recovery partners here: http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=PBJW57

Comment: Well that's great then... I haven't got any encryption enabled if that makes a difference?

Comment: Referring to the question being put on hold, I am not really sure what I need to say. I have already stated in the question that "I don't mind if the drive dies completely, as long as I can get the data onto the new drive. Please can someone help me recover the data, thanks in advance."

Comment: WD My Passport has hardware encryption so it's encrypting the data by default. You can only configure the password but the encryption will be active even without one.
However if you haven't changed the cable I strongly recommend that you do it. Make sure to use a short, good quality USB 3.0 cable. Those things cause problems way more often that you'd expect.

Comment: Hmm just tried with a different cable that works for a different external HDD and I'm getting the same problem. I guess this drive's dead then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things I would recommend trying to recover the drive.  First, to diagnose the problem, I'd try the following:

- Plug the drive into another computer, preferably your Mac if you still have it.  I've had drives that have done the same thing that you're describing on Windows that I've been able to get the data off of using my Mac and/or Linux computer.
- Plug the drive into a different port on your computer.  If you're using a desktop, try using a usb port in the back instead of the front or vice versa.
- Try using [S.M.A.R.T.](http://www.howtogeek.com/134735/how-to-see-if-your-hard-drive-is-dying/) to see what's going on with your drive, if you still have the ability to (i.e. one of the above two things worked).

Sometimes the above is enough to get your computer to read the drive long enough for you to pull the data off, other times it's not.  From the way you're describing your problem, I'm guessing that either your enclosure is failing or your drive has a ton of bad sectors on it, which is causing your computer to read it super slowly and hang a lot as it tries to deal with the bad sectors.  (As a bit of personal experience, I've seen these problems with WD drives more than other types of drives.)  If the above doesn't work, try the following:

- Get an external enclosure.  I've had a lot of enclosures fail on me, but I've had good luck with the Vantec CB-ISATAU2 model.  It's not an enclosure so much as an adapter, but it's reliable and has worked for me on many different drives I've had the need to recover data off of.  Just pulling the drive out of your enclosure and putting it in this might be enough to get you access to your data if your enclosure was the problem.
- Use the CANE Live Forensics CD to try to recover your data.  I'd recommend either the dd_rescue or myrescue tools for starters, as they'll attempt to copy the data off of the drive and deal with any bad sectors.  Once the data is off, you can work on recovering it at your leisure.  There is plenty of information available about these tools and other ones on this distro to get you started if you want to go this route.  This distro packs together a huge number of tools that are extremely useful in recovering data.
- [This LifeHacker post](http://lifehacker.com/5982339/diy-data-recovery-tricks-for-when-your-hard-drive-goes-belly-up) has more things you can try and criteria for when you want to try them.

These are some things that might work for getting your data back, but if you can afford it and the data is important to you, you might want to pay a company that specializes in data recovery (not a general IT repair shop).  The more you do with the drive, the larger chance that the drive will become irrecoverable.  If you don't have the money to pay by the GB of recovered data, what I've outlined and linked above should point you in the right direction to start out with.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was gonna try it this weekend but it appears it's not going to work. I'll see what happens.

Comment: Using `wmic` the drive reports as "OK" and this is the longest the drive's been spinning for, however I'm still getting the other problems.